# Finding The Goblin Tinkerer in Terraria Xbox360

Tags: terraria-console

I know other People already asked this question, but I just cant't find the Goblin Tinkerer. I am really close to defeating Skeletron, but many are telling me he is not in the Dungeon. Help!?

Comment: By the way, he can spawn in any underground area, including the dungeon itself.

Answer (score 1):

The goblin can show up randomly in caves , as it is not necessary to kill* Skeletron Martar it then appears .

Comment: He can only show up after defeating the goblin army at least once. That's the only requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be on hard mode.Defeat the goblin army and then you can randomly find him underground in the places you've already explored.
But you can't see his icon on the map until you see him on your screen while exploring. 
    Hope I helped.

Comment: Hardmode ? No way. You must have confused him with the Wizard NPC, as he spawns randomly in caves when hardmode is activated.

Comment: Oh,I thought he only spawned in Hardmode because I always find him in hardmode.

Comment: Well, it's all a matter of luck, so it could have happened for the unlucky ones to go in hardmode before finding him :)

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to defeat Skeletron, or in fact *any* other bosses for the Tinkerer to spawn.

You must complete the [Goblin Army](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Army) event at least once in that world. For the event to trigger (from the Terraria wiki):

- You must have at least one person in the game with at least 200 current life.
- You must have smashed at least one Shadow Orb or Crimson Heart.

Once these conditions are met, the Goblin Army has a 1/3 chance of happening each day. Alternatively, you can craft a [Goblin Battle Standard](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Battle_Standard) using Wood and Tattered Cloth at a Loom, and use this item to trigger the Goblin Army. Tattered Cloth can be obtained by defeating Goblin Scouts in the outer 2/3 of the world (ie. closer to the Oceans, far from the spawn point).

After completing the Goblin Army event, the Goblin Tinkerer can be found randomly tied up underground. Keep a close eye when adventuring and he should be fairly easy to spot. Also, if he spawns underground and the player walks too far away he can respawn at another location. Speak to him and release him, and he will move into the next available house.

Comment: Great answer. We tend to prefer you reword a copy paste from the internet, though. Especially if you fail to reference your source

Comment: How did I fail to reference the source? The source is literally linked in the same sentence.

Comment: Edited the answer to add a source. Was that why I had a downvote?

Answer (score -1):

You can find him anywhere underground, possibly even the dungeon. So I suggest looking underground. If he's not there, he is in the dungeon.

Comment: Note: I found him next to d.a